# How does user access for full disk encryption work?

Tags: encryption

When installing Ubuntu 12.10 and higher you get an option to [encrypt the entire drive](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2012/11/privacy-ubuntu-1210-full-disk-encryption) (not just the home directory). What encryption mechanism is used for this, and what kind of access permissions are supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use full disk encryption, you have to enter your key once during boot to unlock your hard drive. It does not provide file access protection - once unlocked, any user (local or remote) has "normal" access. The use case for the full disk encryption is if your hard drive gets stolen or something, no one can access your system/data.

Answer (score 1):

The encryption mechanism:

> uses Cryptsetup's defaults with LUKS for AES in XTS_plain64 mode, a 256 bit key with SHA1 password hashing run through 1 second of PBKDF2, so the amount of iterations depends on your CPU strength. System (/ or 'root'), home and swap areas are all tucked into one encrypted logical volume. The boot partition must be separate in Linux FDE, no matter which configuration or distro and for most, it must also be unencrypted (exceptions: Arch and Gentoo) so /boot is open to attackers with physical access to the computer. Ubiquity makes an ext2 boot partition around 250 MB in size.  [[Source - has a good overview]](http://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu)

The access permissions supported are basically "locked" and "unlocked"; anyone with a valid passphrase can unlock and read any file (assuming physical access = root access).